# Unzip a multi-file zip archive in freebsd

Tags: archiving, 7-zip, unzip

I created a multi-file zip archive of some files using 7zip on Windows to allow more easy uploading to my server. I now want to unzip this archive on the server, but I get this error:

```
[user@host ~/uploads/Android_SS_VM]$ unzip Android_SS.zip.001
Archive:  Android_SS.zip.001
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of Android_SS.zip.001 or
        Android_SS.zip.001.zip, and cannot find Android_SS.zip.001.ZIP, period.
```

How can I extract this archive in FreeBSD?

Answer (score 2):

I think the error message is telling you that `unzip` needs the *last* part as the argument (not the first):

```
# replace .999 with the last number of your multi-part
$ unzip Android_SS.zip.999
```

You can also get a commandline version of 7-zip for FreeBSD. [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) is [in the Ports archive](http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/archivers/p7zip.html), and the [official 7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) provides a sourcecode tarball for download.

**Edit**: [Several posts](http://linux.wxs.ro/2008/07/17/how-to-extract-multi-part-zip-files-in-linux/) in [various linux forums](http://www.linux.com/archive/forums/topic/5326) indicate that using `unzip` on a multipart archive actually needs some other steps:

```
# combine all multiparts
$ cat Android_SS.zip.* > Android_SS.zip

# fix the zip
$ zip -F Android_SS.zip

# unzip
$ unzip Android_SS.zip
```